# Getting a segmentation fault while implementing Trie in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, trie

Another day another seg fault I don't understand, I'm trying to implement tries for the first time and it is proving to be quite some challenge, I think it would be very helpful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, would probably help me understand OOP better too I suppose, because I think the error is related to that.

> The fault happens while searching and I wasn't able to understand it using the debugger myself.

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::string, std::cout, std::vector;

class TrieNode {
    private: 
        bool isLeaf;
        vector<TrieNode*> ar = vector<TrieNode*>(26);

    public:
        TrieNode() {
            isLeaf = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) ar[i] = nullptr;
        }

    void insert(TrieNode *root, string key) {
        TrieNode *crawl = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) {
            if(!crawl->ar[key[i]]) {
                crawl->ar[key[i]] = new TrieNode();
            }
            crawl = crawl->ar[key[i]];
        }
        crawl->isLeaf = true;
    }

    bool search(TrieNode *root, string key) {
        TrieNode *crawl = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) {
            if(!crawl->ar[key[i]]) {
                return false;
            }
            crawl = crawl->ar[key[i]];
        }
        return crawl->isLeaf;
    }
};

int main() {
    TrieNode* head = new TrieNode();
    head->insert(head, "hello");
    cout << head->search(head, "hello");
}
```

Comment: "The fault happens while searching and I wasn't able to understand it using the debugger myself." When exactly does the segfault occur?

Comment: You probably want std::string length not size, but I doubt that's your problem.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX on second iteration of the for loop

Comment: Check these lines: `if(!crawl->ar[key[i]])`: `key[i]`is may be an out of bounds index for `r`.

Comment: Don't use naked new and raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr`. `search` is not accessing the `this` object, so you can make it static. Same for `insert`. Why do you expect `crawl->ar[key[i]]` to do something useful (key is a string, how should the characters in key be valid indices into `ar`?)? You would see that problem when using `vector::at` instead of `vector::operator[]`.

Comment: @WernerHenze I overlooked that by mistake, I've used that format so many times, I was stuck at trying to initialize vector outside of a method for a while and by the time I found that, I guess my head was too far gone! I don't know the proper use of unique and smart pointers, by static you mean make my function static? If you could find the time, can you add an answer using unique/ smart pointer with some explanation? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `ar[key[i]]` to something like `ar[key[i]-'a']` if your string is say always lower-case.

Basically, key[i] is a char in the range of ['a'-'z']. When it's implicitly converted to an int, it's not in the range of [0,25], but rather equal to their ascii values.

Comment: @gh05t your debugger should have told you

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wasn't watching the experssion key[i] and the ar wasn't visible either, I'm just learning how to use it properly, I'm sure it could've been caught, also I was using gdbonline not my vscode debugger which I'm more used to.